# Eclipse, Set Version to Revert To

Tags: java, eclipse, file, version, revert

I'm using eclipse to write a small game and I now realize I want to make a big change to the core of my program. What is the best way to save two versions of the same code separately (if something goes wrong) and test them side by side? Is it a good idea to simply copy paste one file into a new one and work from there?

Thanks

P.S. 
I know about reverting to a previous version or time but I've gotten it into my head that this is different, am I wrong?

Comment: A version control system; git, subversion, mercurial, etc.

Comment: You want to search the net for "version control systems". Which tool you want to pick really depends on the amount of time you want to spend to learn about it. git or mercurial are those that most people would be using today. Also depends on the OS you are working with. Besides: asking for tools, libraries and such is actually **not** what stackoverflow should be used for. We help with specific programming problems; not with tooling.